# Como mudar a posição de elementes bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu queria mudar a posição de elementos de uma página formada em bootstrap 
Como apresento nas seguintes imagens conforme redimensiono a página os botões [EN][PT][ES] mudam de posições e eu acredito que é atraves de `@media` no css.

O meu problema é quando redimensiono até um certo ponto os botões são apresentados como mostro na segunda imagem, e eu queria que se mantivessem como apresentados na primeira imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não entenda bem a questão comente que eu edito para esclarecer o melhor possivel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, corrigi o problema, passo a explicar:

No bootstrap existem colunas onde são marcadas com classes, as que usei foram col-sm-3  col-sm-6  col-sm-3
antes eram 
col-sm-3  col-sm-7  col-sm-2

então ao aumentar a colunda col-sm-2 para col-sm-3 e reduzindo a coluna onde tem a busca de col-sm-7  para  col-sm-6 então os botões passaram a ter mais espaço corrigindo o problema.

Caso não foi claro a minha explicação, comente que eu edito